# Probability of drawing same items from a pool

Tags: statistics

Is there a way to calculate the probability of drawing the same item from a pool in subsequent drawings?

For example, I have 500 questions in a pool. I draw 50 questions.

I then start with the same 500 questions and draw another 50 questions.

How can I calculate how many questions will overlap with the first 50 questions?

Also, what's the probability of a question *not* being drawn at all after N redraws?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Suppose size of the pool is $N$, size of the draw is $d$ and $I$ is size of the intersection of two draws. Then to construct the second draw given the first, you need to pick $I$ elements from the first draw and $d-I$ elements from $I$'s complement. Hence for $0\leq i\leq d$:
   $$P(I=i)=\frac{\binom d i \binom {N-d}{d-i}}{\binom N d}$$
   which is a hypergeometric distribution with parameters $(d,N,d)$.
2. The probability that a given element of the first draw is also an element of the second draw is $d/N$ and there are $d$ elements in the first draw, hence by linearity of expectation

$$E(I)=\frac{d^2}N$$

3. A given question is drawn in a single draw with probability $d/N$. Hence it's not drawn after $r$ draws with probability $$(1-d/N)^r$$

From here you can also conclude the expected number of distinct question drawn after $r$ draws is

$$N(1-(1-d/N)^r)$$

Comment: Thank you - that will be of great help in allowing us to determine how many questions we need to write for our students.